# Powershell NON-Cmdlet: Move User to new OU via System.DirectoryServices Namespaces

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am logged in on domain Y and the AD with the User I wish to move is located in domain X (windows 2003 server without ADAM)

How would one move user X from an OU to another OU within the same domain through the System.DirectoryServices Namespaces method?

This is how far I've gotten:

```
$user = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($context, $idtype, $sam)
```

Doesn't state here: [UserPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had to do it without either the QAD cmdlets or the ADAM cmdlets for some time, so this is untested and from memory, but I think something like:

```
$root = [adsi]''
$searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($root)
$searcher.Filter = "(&(ObjectClass=User)(Name=SomeUser))"
$userObject = $searcher.FindOne()
$path = $userObject.Properties.ADSPath
$targetOU = [adsi]("LDAP://OU=Target,DC=SomeDomain,DC=com")
$ADUser = [adsi]($path)
$ADUser.PSBase.moveto($targetOU)
```

Comment: Yeah tell me about it, migrating a Windows 2003 Server is just bla. However I must of been abit unclear, I need to go via the "$user = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($context, $idtype, $sam)" because I have to log into my SU account on the 2003 domain!

Comment: If you do $user.GetType(), what type object is it?

Comment: "$ADUser = [adsi]($path)
$ADUser.PSBase.moveto($targetOU)" you state does not help as I need authorization through my SU account on that server. Is there a way to allow my credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other solution :

```
# MoveObject
$OuDest=[ADSI] "LDAP://mach:389/ou=Commerciaux,dc=societe,dc=fr" 
$objUODest.MoveHere("LDAP://cn=Mickey,ou=Ventes,dc=societe,dc=fr", “cn=Mickey")
```

And

```
# Rename
$Ou=[adsi] "LDAP://mach:389/ou=Ventes,dc=societe,dc=fr"
$Ou.MoveHere("LDAP://cn=PetitMickey,ou=Ventes,dc=societe,dc=fr", "cn=PetitMickeyBis")
```

If you need to authentify :

```
$OuDest = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://FQDN name or @IP",$User,$password)
```