# System.DirectoryServices Namespaces -> move user OU?

Tags: powershell

How do I use System.DirectoryServices Namespaces to move a user from one OU to another?

I know how to do it via CMDLETs and the old PSBase.moveto way. Are these the only ways? I am trying t oavoid CMDlets and PSBase.moveto.

ben looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145037.aspx

Anyone know?

Comment: Unless I am missing something, isn't this the same question that you already asked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Powershell NON-Cmdlet: Move User to new OU via System.DirectoryServices Namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315209/powershell-non-cmdlet-move-user-to-new-ou-via-system-directoryservices-namespac)

Comment: Ahh it was, now when I looked again thought it was deleted! The reason to this question is because I have to loginto my su account in the otherdomain.

Comment: Yes this is, sorry! Thought the other one was deleted!

Answer (score 1):

Here you are :

```
# MoveObject
$OuDest=[ADSI] "LDAP://mach:389/ou=Commerciaux,dc=societe,dc=fr" 
$objUODest.MoveHere("LDAP://cn=Mickey,ou=Ventes,dc=societe,dc=fr", “cn=Mickey")
```

And

```
# Rename
$Ou=[adsi] "LDAP://mach:389/ou=Ventes,dc=societe,dc=fr"
$Ou.MoveHere("LDAP://cn=PetitMickey,ou=Ventes,dc=societe,dc=fr", "cn=PetitMickeyBis")
```

---

Edited

If you need to authentify :

```
$OuDest = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://FQDN name or @IP",$User,$password)
$OuDest = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://mach:389/ou=Commerciaux,dc=societe,dc=fr",$User,$password)
```

Comment: I keep getting Access is denied. i need to run the commands via my SU account on that domain, I don't know where to stick in the $username and $password variables :/